# Passing a Custom Cells image views image to a new view controller

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view controller which has a `UITableView` with some custom cells.

Within the custom cells I have a main `UIImageView`. I add a tap gesture recogniser to the image view, so that when the image is tapped the `handleImageTap` method is called.

**Question**
What I am trying to do is pass the image from the selected `UIImageView` (from the specific cell) into a new View Controller.

When the handleImageTap is called I run the following:

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;

// send the image instead of self when firing the segue
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"remindMeTurnInfo" sender:imageView];
```

I then have the following in the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"remindMeTurnInfo"]) {
        UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)sender;
        MESPlayedTurnReminderViewController *VC = segue.destinationViewController;
        VC.mainImageView.image = imgView.image;
}
```

The above does not work the image is not passed across. How can I get the image from the selected cells image view to the new controller?

**Also**
Sometimes when the image view of the cell is selected the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is called. This is not correct and should not be called when the image view is tapped. This doesn't appear to be all the time, is there anyway to ensure this is not called?

I also need a reference to the cell that the imageview is within for the `prepareForSegue` method. How do I get the reference for the cell that the imageview is within, when the cell is (should not be) actually selected here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the approach.

Putting a `UIImage` on the destination Controller instead. Then in the viewDidLoad of this controller I pass the image into the `UIImageView`. I imagine this is because the image view is not created yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has 2 problems.

First, you should not use table view cells to store data. Table view cells are view objects. They display data. When the user triggers an action on a cell, you should figure out the indexPath of the cell, use that info to look up the data in your model (the image for the selected row or section/row, in your case) and use that.

Second, you should never try to manipulate  another view controller's views. Treat the other VC's views as private. This is a biggie. Reaching into another VC and touching its views violates the encapsulation of the two VCs and means that the VC doing the touching becomes dependent on the appearance of the "touched" VC. Bad. Then you can't change the appearance of the touched VC without breaking other code. It also doesn't work right after creating the new VC, because it's views don't exist yet.

Instead, you should add an "imageToUse" property to the other view controller, and set THAT in the prepareForSegue method. Then the second view controller can take the image and install it in it's image view in it's viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had already figured out that I needed to pass a UIImage instead of trying to update the image views image prop directly. What do you mean by your first part, you should not use table view cells to store data. Where do I mention that I am? The cell has a UIImageView with an image in, I am just passing that specific image to another controller.